# How to shrink a TableLayout column to a minWidth?

Tags: android, tablelayout

If coloumn 3 has large text, column 2 disappears. Column 2 also disappears if I set `android:stretchColumns="2,3"`. I'd like to set a `minWidth`s to column 2. But this attribute is getting ignored.

I'm helping myself right now by setting `android:stretchColumns="3"` and `android:shrinkColumns="3"` and applying a `maxWidth` to the TextView on position 2. This almost does the job, but minWidth would be more the solution.

```
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:shrinkColumns="2,3"
                android:stretchColumns="3" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextViewIdLabel"
                        style="@style/overlay_content"
                        android:text="@string/id_label"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextViewIdValue"
                        style="@style/overlay_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextViewPersonIdLabel"
                        style="@style/overlay_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/person_id_label"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextViewPersonIdValue"
                        style="@style/overlay_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />
                </TableRow>
                <!-- I skipped the other rows -->
           </TableLayout>
```

This is the used style, if you wonder:

```
<style name="overlay_content">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/foreground_color_on_dark_background</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>
```

*Update:*

As the answers came I found out more about my requirements which I summed up in this comment: [How to shrink a TableLayout column to a minWidth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939067/how-to-shrink-a-tablelayout-column-to-a-minwidth?noredirect=1#comment45802854_28734646)

Comment: How about setting weight per column instead of `android:shrinkColumns ` and `android:stretchColumns` . So for column 1 you could set 0.2 weight, 0.3 for column 2 and 0.5 for column 3 and so on?

Comment: @Slartibartfast So far, your solution is the only work around that always ensures that all columns are displayed at least partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this might be the practical workaround you need, so moving my comment to answer. Maybe this can be improved though, essentially be dilligent about setting these weights to suit your app

How about setting weight per column instead of `android:shrinkColumns` and `android:stretchColumns` . So for column 1 you could set 0.2 weight, 0.3 for column 2 and 0.5 for column 3 and so on

Answer (score 2):

> **How to shrink a TableLayout column to a minWidth?**

```
Actually it is simple, just TextView layout_width="wrap_content" can do
that, the reason not working in your style is that 'wrap_content' should
not work together with TextView 'ellipsize', they are conflict. So you need
one seperate syle 'overlay_slide' for the column that has long text.

So use 'overlay_content' for columns those have short text, use    
'overlay_slide' for columns that have long text.

Besides I suppose the 'ellipsize' in your style is not working because
seems two items missing:

    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>

finally in the column that has long text, you also need:

    android:layout_weight="1"

to use all rest of space for 'ellipsize'.
```

> **Remove `android:shrinkColumns="2,3" android:stretchColumns="3"` from `TableLayout`**

> **Solution working styles and layout:**

```
//remove 'ecllipze' related items from 'overlay_content' 
<style name="overlay_content">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/foreground_color_on_dark_background</item>
   <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>    
</style>

//remove 'android:layout_width' from 'overlay_slide'
<style name="overlay_slide">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/foreground_color_on_dark_background</item>
   <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
   <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>

   <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
   <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>

   <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>


<TableLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 >

   <TableRow
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/TextViewIdLabel"
           style="@style/overlay_content"              
           android:text="@string/id_label"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/TextViewIdValue" 
           style="@style/overlay_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>

      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/TextViewPersonIdLabel"
           style="@style/overlay_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
           android:text="@string/person_id_label"
           android:textStyle="bold"/>

      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/TextViewPersonIdValue"
           style="@style/overlay_slide"
           android:layout_weight="1" 
           android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />  

   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

> **Screenshot from my testing: (Portrait and Landscape)**

```
My test long text column is text 'Column 1 ... Column 8'
```

[image: In Portrait]
[image: In landscape]

Comment: Column 3 will disappear then, if the other columns are too large.

Comment: So your `TextView` sliding `<item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>` not working? then you have to give a fixed width for the `TextView` of column 3 to make sliding work.

Comment: You also can try all columns have `TextView` width `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: Yes, sliding is already implemented. Your suggestion regarding weight basically equals Slartibartfasts comment, which I implemented now.

Comment: @OneWorld I just got solution that is working perfect, I will update my answer soon

Comment: Ok ;) I'm gonna decide about the Bounty in 4 hours

Comment: No problem, enough time

Comment: @OneWorld I just put the solution. please check and test it.

Comment: Your effort to answer my question is great. Thanks ;) But Slartibartfasts answer just nails it in a view sentences. I know the caviats of sliding text and handled them. Maybe you can't see it, because my XML of my question is old. But I wasn't asking for marquee. Your suggestion has a problem: the last column will disappear, if the other columns are too large.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the width of a column that way.  The width is only defined by the widest row in that column.  If you have no display there, there will be no width.  You can adjust this by adjusting the textview for that row.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewIdValue"
            style="@style/overlay_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:minEms="4"              <!--    You can use either of these -->
            android:minWidth="40dp" />
```

The trade-off here is that you might run out of room and your other columns will run off the end, but you can adjust your text size to correct that, even if you have to overwrite your style with `android:textSize="10dp"`

This code appears to be working for me, but I also changed your TableLayout width from "0dp" to "match_parent".

```
  <TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:shrinkColumns="3"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewIdLabel"
        style="@style/overlay_content"
        android:text="id_label"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewIdValue"
        style="@style/overlay_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewPersonIdLabel"
        style="@style/overlay_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="person_id_label"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:minEms="4"
        android:minWidth="40dp" />
    <!-- You can use either of these -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewPersonIdValue"
        style="@style/overlay_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />
</TableRow>
<!-- I skipped the other rows -->
```

Comment: You applied `minWidth`to column 1. But I was talking about column 2 which disappeares when column 3 is large. There are 4 columns 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood the question.  Are you trying to get all columns equal?  Does column 2 need to be shrinkable?  From what I think I understand, you can either go with your `maxWidth` method while setting that column to be stretchable and not shrinkable, or go with the weight method they are suggesting.

Comment: I wanted to use the space as efficient as possible. I thought `shrinkColumns` was a good property to achieve that goal. However, `shrinkColumns` and `stretchColumns` can make columns disappear. Something I certainly don't want. That's why I tried to combine `shrinkColumn` with a `minWidth`. However, `minWidth` is not recognized by `TableLayout`. That's why I asked this question. Slartibartfast brang me on the right track then. He suggested to avoid using `shrinkColumns`/`stretchColumns` properties and to use `weight` instead. That seems to be the best solution for my needs so far.